# CodeIgniter: Hooks (pre_controller) loading helpers

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to load the cookie helper in my pre_controller hook for a 'remember me' function on our site. I thought that creating an instance of the CI object with $ci =& get_instance(); would allow me to access to loading helpers but this is not the case.

Thoughts?

```
 $ci =& get_instance();
 $ci->load->helper('cookie');
 // does not load
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `pre_controller` hook executes before the super object has been fully constructed, so `get_instance()` can't work - the static object it returns a reference to hasn't yet been initialized.

Consider using the `post_controller_constructor` hook instead; your controller's constructor will have executed, and the CI super object will be available for use.

Answer (score 16):

The problem with the post_controller_constructor is it runs after the constructor (funnily enough) and if you use Controller constructors for lots of things this can be a problem.

If it's not a problem for you (your helper wont affect anything run or loaded in your constructors) fair enough, if it IS a problem you have two solutions.

1. Instead of the hook put your code in [MY_Controller](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/MY_Controller_-_how_to_extend_the_CI_Controller/)
2. Create MY_Controller and add in a custom hook point.

   ```
   class MY_Controller extends Controller
   {

       function MY_Controller()
       {
           parent::Controller();
           $GLOBALS['EXT']->_call_hook('pre_controller_constructor');
       } 
   }
   ```

Note that if you're using CodeIgniter 3.0 or later, the function `_call_hook` was renamed to `call_hook`.