# Run a function each time a page loads in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, pageload

I have previously only made web applications in Asp.Net MVC, and there you can use OnResultExecuted in an "ActionFilter" set on the BaseController to run a method each time an action method is executed (i.e. basically each time anyone visits any page in the application).

How would I do the same thing in CodeIgniter/PHP?

EDIT:

I tried using post_controller_constructor instead, according to one of the suggestions, but that doesn't help:

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'] = array(
                                'class'    => 'PreController',
                                'function' => 'getIp',
                                'filename' => 'preController.php',
                                'filepath' => 'hooks'
                                );
```

I still get Undefined property: PreController::$input (I just haven't renamed the class called, that shouldn't matter if it is still called PreController for the moment).

But the fact remains I do not have access to the input property... Obviously I don't have access to the Input Class, so how do I do that? I belive if I had done the same thing in a Controller it would have been ok, but from a hook? How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use CodeIgniter hooks for that: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html

There are several "events" you can hook into, check the bottom of the documentation page.

---

In response to the comment:

Re-read your comment and edit... it seems that you're assuming that your hook class is the current controller -- it isn't. The current controller is whatever matches the URI/route mapping (for example, `site.com/users/view/1` would be using the `Users` controller, and not your hook handler `PreController` class). The hook handler can be a simple PHP class not inheriting from `CI_Controller`.

The first thing you need to do in the hook handler is to get hold of the actual controller, that will contain the Input reference and others.

```
class HookHandler {
    function post_controller_constructor() {
        $ci =& get_instance();
        // ... now you can use $ci->input and other controller members
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks, that's just what I was looking for. Just a follow-up question, though. I need to be able to access things like methods in the Input Class and User Agent Class, e.g. in the hook. To get ip address of the user, check for robots etc. But how can I access these from the hook class configured. Say I put my hook class (PreController) into the folder hooks. If I try to access the input class by e.g. echo $this->input->ip_address(); it doesn't work, undefined is the error message... Please note that I am a newbie :-)

Comment: The `pre_controller` hook gets executed before the super object has been fully constructed so you won't be able to access the input or user agent classes.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196559/codeigniter-hooks-pre-controller-loading-helpers.  The solution would be to use the `post_controller_constructor` hook instead.

Comment: @AndersSvensson: It's like birderic mentioned, you should hook up to post_controller_constructor. That gives you an initialized CI instance (including URI segments, session data, and other goodies) and you can still do stuff like redirects to a different controller/action/URI.

Comment: Understood your last question after a bit of digging. Please post actual code next time, it would be easier to understand and "debug".

Comment: Ah, ok I had no idea it worked like that, a lot is still a bit foggy about how things work in CI. I actually did the stuff I needed in a MY_Controller when I didn't get this to work, just so I could move on, but I'll try this. Thanks!