# Unable to load the requested file: helpers - codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I created an `function helper` for using in view now the function helper   not work and I got this **error:**

> Unable to load the requested file: helpers/mainhelper_helper.php

**my helper:**

```
 function getCategories($id){

     $CI =& get_instance();
     $CI->db->select('*');
     $CI->db->from('categories');
     $CI->db->where('cat_parent_id',$id);
    return $CI->db->get()->result();
}
```

I added my helper into **autoload.php:**

```
$autoload['helper'] =  array('form','url' , 'mainHelper');
```

Comment: what is your helper file name ?

Comment: change the name to `mainHelper_helper.php` and it will work.

Comment: your answer is correct please post your answer .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter: Hooks (pre\_controller) loading helpers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196559/codeigniter-hooks-pre-controller-loading-helpers)

Answer (score 2):

change the name of your helper file to `mainHelper_helper.php` and it will work.